# How to draw shadows properly around (but not underneath) without background on View?

Tags: android, android-view

I have a `RecyclerView` that hosts *items*.

Each *item* has a `StateListAnimator` which increases the translationZ as  the user touches it. Basically raising the *item* up to the meet the users finger.

Now this is all nice and dandy, but if the item has no background, you can see the shadows **underneath** it, and it's not nice.

I can simply fix this by setting the *item*'s background to white, but it presents a nasty overdraw (the window background is also white, and I need it to be white). **Is there any way of having the shadows basically just draw outside the View, but not underneath it?**

I'm currently using

```
setOutlineProvider(ViewOutlineProvider.BOUNDS);
```

On the view which makes the shadow respect it's bounds even if it has no background set.

Comment: if your current view is filled with RecyclerView only, then try a hack by just removing the background color of layout and providing RecyclerView item a white background.

Comment: @vipul_asri I have a background for the whole window, unfortunately.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of what you have? not sure I understood your question

Comment: @DanieleSegato I cant post any pictures of the app itself yet Im afraid; Ill try explaining it better. Imagine a View with elevation, it casts a shadow underneath it. If the View is transparent however, the shadow itself is visible under it. I want the shadow to show outside the view, but not underneath it - without any background set on the view.

Comment: just blur out the staff of your app you can't show and leave only the interested part visible

Answer (score 0):

> Considering that this is quite an abstract question, and I cant
>   provide any images of what I mean, I still wanted to let you know that
>   I resolved it, and its quite a fun way of solving it I think. I hope
>   someone else out there will have use of this.

So, a `View` casts a shadow, if the view has no background you see the shadow underneath the view itself.

But having a background set on the view may introduce performance problems if there already is a background (e.g. on the window itself, or the container view).

So to resolve this you can simply have an animated drawable selector that fades in/out the background with the `StateListAnimator`.

**StateListAnimator**: (*raise*)

```
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="translationZ"
        android:valueTo="@dimen/touch_raise"/>
</item>
<item>
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="translationZ"
        android:valueTo="0dp"/>
</item>
```

**Selector**: (*selector_to_white*)

```
<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

**And in layout**:

```
<View
    //View width, etc 
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/raise"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_to_white"
    android:outlineProvider="bounds"/>
```

And voila, there you have it. A view that casts a shadow underneath itself that isnt visible, even if the view has no background. Perfect for my case, hopefully useful for yours.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem:
[image]

I can't believe I didn't think of this right away, but the solution is simply to draw an opaque background in addition to the desired one if `Color.alpha(background) != 255`. So something like this:

```
val backgroundColor = background.color
if (Color.alpha(backgroundColor) != 255) {
    background.color = backgroundColors.defaultColor
    drawBackground(canvas, width, height)
    background.color = backgroundColor
}
drawBackground(canvas, width, height)
```